# Padding a numpy array at the start of an array

Tags: python, numpy, padding

I need to pad a numpy array at the start of the array if it is not 8 bits long. 
For example:

> If I have an array which is [1 0 0] it should be [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0].
>   
> However, if it is already [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] (8 bits long), I do
>   not have to do anything with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `numpy.pad` in *constant* mode with a *pad_width* `(8-len(a), 0)` which pads `8-len(a)` zeros to the left, and nothing to the right:

```
a = [1, 0, 0]

np.pad(a, (8-len(a), 0), 'constant')
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate the width you need to pad. Then make an array with zeros of the calculated width. After that, concatenate this array with your original array. Check the code snippet below:

```
pad_width = 8 - length_of_your_array
pad_array = np.zeros(pad_width)
desired_array = np.concatenate((pad_array, your_array))
```